# Access to variable in closure

Tags: c#, closures, resharper, predicate

I know there has been a lot topics about that issue on SO and there is also a great post from [Eric Lippert](http://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/). Still I'm not quite sure what is happening in the following code and the reason for the Resharper warning:

```
public class Class
{
  public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class GenericClass<T>
{
  public virtual bool Exists(Predicate<T> match)
  {
    return true;
  }
}

public class Main
{
  public void Test()
  {
    var list = new List<Class>();
    var list2 = new GenericClass<Class>();

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
      if (list2.Exists(o => o.Id == item.Id)) // access to variable in closure on item
    }
  }
}
```

This can be easily fixed by this:

```
var localCopy = item;
if (list2.Exists(o => o.Id == localCopy.Id))
```

As far as I understand all closures which are created in the exists does reference the same instance if localCopy, correct? But this should not be an issue since the exists is evaluated instantly right? So where am I wrong here?

Comment: What is giving you the warning? Sounds like a Resharper warning and not a C# compiler one.

Comment: Yes it's a reshraper warning, thanks for the info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But this should not be an issue since the exists is evaluated instantly right?

Yes, `GenericClass.Exists` evaluates the lambda eagerly, but ReSharper doesn't know that.

All ReSharper knows is that you're passing a closure to another method - that method *might* execute the lambda lazily, hence the warning.

---

> Is there any way to tell resharper that, for that method, there is no need for the warning?

Looking at the documentation, it *seems* you could decorate the predicate parameter with the [`InstantHandleAttribute`](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#InstantHandleAttribute) attribute.

> Tells code analysis engine if the parameter is completely handled when the invoked method is on stack. If the parameter is a delegate, indicates that delegate is executed while the method is executed. If the parameter is an enumerable, indicates that it is enumerated while the method is executed

See here for how to install JetBrains code annotation attributes: [Annotations in Source Code](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__Annotations_in_Source_Code.html)

Comment: Small correction: This is not a compiler warning, presumably resharper.

Comment: Sorry one more. Resharper do knows about eager Linq methods(For instance try `Enumerable.Any`). in this case `Exists` is OP's own method and hence resharper doesn't know it. btw  `Enumerable.Exists` doesn't really exist ;)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel 9am, haven't had my coffee yet u_u I mistook `List.Exists` for `Enumerable.Contains`... And you're right, this isn't even `List.Exists`, it's `GenericClass.Exists`... I've fixed my post again, thanks!

Comment: Is there any way to tell resharper that, for that method, there is no need for the warning? I know I can locally disable it for that call. But is there a way to turn it of for a method?